# Angular Form Validation only works, when input then delete

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, validation, controls

I want the submit button for my form to be blank when there is no input. But my problem is the submit only blanks out, when you put input, than delete it.

```
<form [formGroup]="resourceForm" (ngSubmit)="createResource(title.value, link.value, description.value)">
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <label for="title">Titel</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input #title formControlName="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="title"
                  placeholder="Titel"
                  [class.is-invalid]="resourceForm.get('title').invalid && resourceForm.get('title').touched">
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Titel darf nicht leer sein
                </div>
              </div>

              <label for="link">Link (Optional)</label>
              <input #link type="text" formControlName="link" class="form-control" id="link" placeholder="Link">

              <label for="description">Beschreibung</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <textarea #description formControlName="description" type="text" class="form-control"
                  id="description"
                  [class.is-invalid]="resourceForm.get('description').invalid && resourceForm.get('description').touched"
                  placeholder="Beschreibung"></textarea>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Beschreibung darf nicht leer sein
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit"
                
                [disabled]="!resourceForm.valid">Hinzufügen</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you show your component code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully recommend this, but this should do what you want:

Instead of `[disabled]="!resourceForm.valid"` Do:

```
[disabled]="!resourceForm.touched || !resourceForm.valid"
```

The problem happens because the form is supposed valid until touched.

Comment: The reason I don't recommend it is because it probbaly wouldn't result in the greatest UX.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason I had this problem was because my typescript code for the Formbuilder was set wrong.

what I had:

```
public resourceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    title : [['', Validators.required]],
    link  : [['', ]],
    description : [['', Validators.required]],

});
```

whats right:

```
public resourceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    title : ['', [Validators.required]],
    link  : ['', []],
    description : ['', [Validators.required]],

});
```